# Cannot find Datagrid's Datasource Property

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datagrid

When writing code like the one below, I cannot get the DataSource property for dataGrid1. I did get the ItemsSource property. Any reason why this is happening?

```
    DataGrid dataGrid1 = new DataGrid();

    var custQuery =
     from cust in db.Customers
     select cust;
    dataGrid1.DataSource = custQuery;
```

Comment: What's the issue exactly? Are you getting a compiler error or is it 'not working' ? Did you DataBind(); ?

Comment: `DataGrid.DataSource` = winforms, `DataGrid.ItemsSource` = WPF, what are you targeting?

Comment: thanks @sa_ddam213. Im working on WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using [WPF DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx), in WPF datagrid you only have `ItemsSource`

Comment: is there any advantage of winforms over wpf

Comment: @MontySwanson it depends, better you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703681/winforms-vs-wpf